# Set TypeFace for GridView in android

Tags: android, android-gridview

I want to change the typeface of my gridview with this code:

```
GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
String[] numbers = new String[] {
                       "1" , "2" ,"3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"
                   };

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, 
                                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                        numbers);
gv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: You want to decide on which Typeface to use during runtime or is it fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

"You have to change the font size in the baseadapter class for the gridview.

Like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      TextView tv;
if (convertView == null) {
    tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 80));
    tv.setTextSize(20);   //text size in gridview
}
```

The gridview just show whatever the

```
gridview.setAdapter(new MyAdapter (thi)); //MyAdapter class is where the getView method run sets the setAdapter to contain."
```